# VBA - Unknown Reason for Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an 'Object variable or With block variance not set' error for a reason I cannot figure out.  With the Error Handler in place, the VBA code appears to work as intended.  I would like to resolve the error, rather than skipping over it.
Can anyone point out where/why this error is occurring?  Or any other suggestions for this code?  Any help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Tx As Range
Dim Rw As Variant

On Error GoTo E_H 'If this error handler is not in effect, and an edit is
                  '    made in column D, the error occurs.

Set Tx = Range("E44")
Set Rw = Rows("47")

If Application.Intersect(Tx, Range(Target.Address)).Value = "x" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Range("C45")
            .Value = "T - 10"
        End With
        With Range("C45").Characters(Start:=36, Length:=5).Font
            .Color = -16776961
        End With
        With Range("I45")
            .Value = "T - 10 - LOS"
        End With
    Rw.Hidden = False
        With Range("B48")
            .Formula = "=B47+1"
        End With
    Sheets("DropDowns").Range("M6").Value = "65"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Else

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Range("C45")
        .Value = "25Ac"
        End With
            With Range("I45")
            .Value = "25Ac - LOS"
        End With
    Rw.Hidden = True
        With Range("B48")
            .Formula = "=B46+1"
        End With
    Sheets("DropDowns").Range("M6").Value = "64"        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

E_H: 
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: I never understand why people do not think it is important to add **what line the error occurs on** in their narrative.

Comment: How can you start colouring individual characters at position 36 if the value of the cell is `"T - 10"`?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Before posting, I removed things that I thought the company I work for would not want me to display.  In doing so, I did not catch that I reduced the number of characters to make that formula non-functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in this line.

```
If Application.Intersect(Tx, Range(Target.Address)).Value = "x" Then
'better and more succinct as,
If Application.Intersect(Tx, Target).Value = "x" Then
```

You do not know if Target intersects `Range("E44")` but you are trying to get the value from the intersection without determining if there is actually anything to get the value from.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("E44"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo E_H
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If LCase(Range("E44").Value) = "x" Then
            With Range("C45")
                .Value = "T - 10"
                .Characters(Start:=36, Length:=5).Font.Color = -16776961
            End With
            Range("I45") = "T - 10 - LOS"
            Range("B48").Formula = "=B47+1"
            Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Worksheets("DropDowns").Range("M6").Value = 65
        Else
            Range("C45") = "I45"
            Range("I45") = "25Ac - LOS"
            Range("B48").Formula = "=B46+1"
            Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Worksheets("DropDowns").Range("M6").Value = 64
        End If
    End If

E_H:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I'm not sure I got your logic flow correct but this is my best guess. If E44 changes and it is now an `x`, unhide row 47, adjust a formula, etc. If E44 changes and it is not an `x` then hide row 47, adjust a formula, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  I will better present my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This line will raise an error when Target does not contain E44:

```
 If Application.Intersect(Tx, Range(Target.Address)).Value = "x" Then
```

`Intersect` will return `Nothing`, and `Nothing` has no `Value` property

A working version might be:

```
 If Not Application.Intersect(Tx, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And _
                                                    Tx.Value = "x" Then
```

Comment: This does work, though when an edit is made to any cell in column D, the macro is activated and, as a result, there is no 'Undo' option available.  Additionally, it slows down making quick changes to any cell in column D.